# Como agrupar os registros pelo ano?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como eu faria para agrupar os anos que são iguais?
na minha tabela os existe um registro com o ano de 2019, um com 2020, e 3 com 2021, porem na hora de mostrar o resultado os registros que estao com o ano de 2021 porem com meses diferentes nao agrupam. Fica tipo:

```
2019
mes 3

2020
mes 4

2021
mes 1
2021
mes 2
2021
mes 3
```

ao invez de:

```
2021
mes 1
mes 2
mes 3
```

Olha como estou fazendo:

```
$sel = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Year(dateFull) as year,  Month(dateFull) as month,  Day(dateFull) as day from usersInfo ORDER BY year, month, day");
    $sel->execute();
    $data = $sel->fetchAll();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['year'] . "<br>";
        echo $value['month'] . "<br>";
        echo $value['day'] . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável para armazenar o ano atual `$current_year = "";` e só imprima se (`if`) verificar que o registro em questão é diferente do ano que foi impresso anteriormente.
Segue código sugerido:

```
$sel = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Year(dateFull) as year,  Month(dateFull) as month,  Day(dateFull) as day from usersInfo ORDER BY year, month, day");
    $sel->execute();
    $data = $sel->fetchAll();
    $current_year = "";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($current_year <> $value['year']){
            echo $value['year'] . "<br>";
            $current_year = $value['year'];
        }
        echo $value['month'] . "<br>";
        echo $value['day'] . "<br>";
    }
```